# MYSQL Query to copy all data in a column from one database to another

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, opencart

I accidentally used the "Generate Description" function on my SEO Tool in Opencart and it overwrote all my product descriptions with the Product Title.

I have over 600+ products and it will be a pain to re-do them all again.

I have a MYSQL backup from 2 months ago which has most of the products except for about 20 which was added after.

I have imported the old backup to a newly created database, what query can i run to copy & overwrite all of the description column data from the backup table to my current table?

They are located in database.oc_product_description.description

Any help is greatly appreciated. This is driving me crazy

Comment: Is your  current table empty?

Comment: No, its populated with what the seo module generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `REPLACE INTO` statement (make backup before operation) if both schema are in the same MySQL instance

**old** means: recovered database
**database** means: current database

```
REPLACE INTO database.oc_product_description 
 SELECT * FROM old.oc_product_description
```

this statement will replace data by primary key

if you dont't want to copy the whole table, then make an update and copy data from old to database (product_id and language_id columns are the primary key)

```
UPDATE database.oc_product_description AS pd1
 INNER JOIN old.oc_product_description AS pd2 ON pd2.product_id = pd1.product_id 
                                             AND pd2.language_id = pd1.language_id
  SET pd1.description = pd2.description
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i instead sat infront the pc for 36 hours straight and re did every single product description,